# Edge Browser automatically closes when automated with selenium 4 version

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge

It does launch successfully but after launching youtube it closes itself automatically almost instantly

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below line of code to keep the browser window open after the WebDriver instance is closed:

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

**Change your code as below:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```